# swift json parse returning Optional

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to parse a json response in swift and am having a hard time doing the trick. when I reference the top level of the json string, and print the value I get an Optional(<__NSSingleObjectArrayI) and then the value of the json

when printed to console I get:

```
Optional(<__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x1c0014180>(
{
ack =     (
    Success
);
paginationOutput =     (
            {
```

then the rest of the json

I don't know what the optional is doing or why its there but it seems to be hindering the rest of the parsing I am trying to do because when I try to go to the next level of the nested values it always returns nil.

the code doing the parsing is as follows

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: endpoint) { (data, response, error) in
        do {
            guard let data = data else {
                return
            }
            guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary else {
                return
            }

            //print(json)
            print(json.object(forKey: "findCompletedItemsResponse"))
            let dictionary1 = json.object(forKey: "findCompletedItemsResponse")

            print(dictionary1)
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
        }.resume()
```

Comment: Well, the `Optional` is in the description of your object, that's basic Swift (How to deal with Optional in Swift). The main issue I think, is that `dictionary1` is in fact an `Array`, not a `Dictionary`. An array with only one object which is a Dictionary, so `dictionary1 = json.object(forKey:"findCompletedItemsResponse").firstObject`. Also, avoid using `NSDictionary` (all NSStuff) when equivalent is available.

Comment: yeah Ive been looking into that, but there is a few items being returned after the first level if I am following the break down correctly (fairly new to json).

Comment: heres a view of the response that comes when the request is ran in the web

`code
"findCompletedItemsResponse": {
    "xmlns": "http://www.marketplace.com/marketplace/search/v1/services",
    "ack": "Success",
    "version": "1.11.0",
    "timestamp": "2015-12-17T22:55:44.894Z",
    "searchResult": {
      "count": "2",
      "item": [
        {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `if-let` to unwrap the values like:

```
if let dictionary1 = json.object(forKey: "findCompletedItemsResponse") {
print(dictionary1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need of `.allowFragments` in swift.

If your `json["findCompletedItemsResponse"]` is dictionary type, then it can parsed as follows:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: endpoint) { (data, response, error) in
    do {
        guard let data = data, let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] else {
            return
        }

        if let dictionary1 = json["findCompletedItemsResponse"] as? [String: Any] {
             print(dictionary1)
        } else {
            print(json["findCompletedItemsResponse"])
        }
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }
    }.resume()
```

Comment: @ZackButcher, If you didn't get your dictionary here, then let me know what `print(json["findCompletedItemsResponse"])` prints.